# C# - Need string in format of characters separated by one and only one comma

Tags: c#, regex, string, replace, character

My goal is to get strings in the format of: "0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 7, 10"
Numbers separated by **one** comma, with no commas in the start or end.

If I have the string "0, 1, 2,,4"
I want to remove just one of the two commas that appear so that I will be left with "0, 1, 2, 4"

I have tried `.Replace(",,", ",")`

However, the problem is that I do not know how many commas there might be.  So for example, I might have a situation like "0,,,,,,,1,,2,3,,,,5" and I need to turn that into "0,1,2,3,5"

How can I accomplish this with C# (.net webforms)?
Maybe something to do with regular expressions?  But I'm not too familiar with those.  Would that be the only way?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is simply

```
string test = "0,,,,,,,1,,2,3,,,,5";
string result = Regex.Replace(test, ",+", ", ");
```

The plus sign after the comma in the pattern expression means

> Matches the previous element one or more times.

[MSDN Quick Reference on Regex expressions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/az24scfc(v=vs.90))

Comment: Perfect, thank you!  The other replies seem like they should work but I went with this one since it was easiest for me to wrap my head around.  Works great!

Answer (score 10):

You could split the string on comma, removing empty elements, and then join the elements back together.

```
string str = "0,,,,,,,1,,2,3,,,,5";
var singleComma = string.Join(",", 
    str.Split(new string[] { "," }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries));
```

While this does not use RegEx, it may be slightly faster as it uses operations specifically designed for this purpose rather than general pattern matching.  Then again, unless you have a very large string or many of them, any performance gain may not matter.

Comment: I agree, specifically written string methods are faster than Regex parsing. On my tests your version is three times faster but on 100000 loops the difference is just 200ms

Comment: I'm used to working with very large amounts of data, so have a built-in bias toward performance.  Most of the time, the best choice in this type of situation is the one that is easy to understand and maintain (which is subjective based on the skill & experience of the developer/team).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of removing unwanted chars, form a new clean string with the numbers in your original string. You can use Regex for this

```
string input = "0,,,  .+=/ garbage,,,,1,,2,3,,,,5";
string output = String.Join(", ", Regex.Matches(input, @"\d+")
                                       .Cast<Match>()
                                       .Select(m => m.Value));
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `string.Split` with `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries` and `string.Join`:

```
string input = "0,,,,,,,1,,2,3,,,,5";
string[] split = input.Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
string result = string.Join(",", split);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach using regex.

You're looking for a regex pattern `\d,?` where:

`\d` will match any digit,

and `,?` will match the char `,` zero or one time.

**[Realtime regex here!](https://regex101.com/r/sK2vE4/1)**

Your code snippet would look something like:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string str = "0,,,,,,,1,,2,3,,,,5";
            string fstr = "";
           Regex RegExp = new Regex(@"\d,?");
           MatchCollection matches = RegExp.Matches(str);
           foreach (Match match in matches) 
           {
               fstr = fstr + match.ToString();
           }

            Console.Write(fstr);
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```